# Turtle library issues

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'am using the Turtle library in python. But the issue is that a Raise Termination error appear 50% of the time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mamane/Desktop/New/Modules/Turtle.py", line 39, in <module>
    tortue  = turtle.Turtle()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 3813, in __init__
    RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

Thanks !

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.color('red','yellow')
bob.begin_fill()
bob.speed(20)

for i in range(2000):
    bob.left(i%180)
    bob.forward(math.sqrt(i)*15)
bob.end_fill()
turtle.done()

Comment: I do not know how to put code in my comment this is my first time question :(

Comment: @Sopraxxx , I made some edits by adding your code. I'm not sure if I got the `bob.end_fill()` indentation correctly (as in, I'm not sure if it is meant to be within the loop). You can change that after reading about formatting.

Answer (score 0):

We can reconstruct the code you supplied in your comment, but add a `print("done")` at the end, you'll see it takes a long time to complete but works fine, at least for me:

```
import turtle
import math

bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.speed('fastest')
bob.color('red', 'yellow')

bob.begin_fill()

for i in range(2000):
    bob.left(i % 180)
    bob.forward(math.sqrt(i) * 15)

bob.end_fill()

print("done")
turtle.done()
```

One you get the "done" message, you should be able to close the window without exception.

> I do not think that what you said is exact because the Raise
>   Terminator Error is appering also in this program :( – Sopraxxx

Looking at your second, simpler example, from your comments:

```
import turtle

keith = turtle.Turtle()
keith.color('red')
keith.shape('square')
keith.fd(100)
keith.left(20)
keith.forward(100)
print('done')
turtle.done()
```

This also works fine, for me, as-is.  However, here's one glitch, in your question, Python's error message says:

```
tortue  = turtle.Turtle()
```

But that doesn't appear in the code you supplied -- so you haven't shown us the *exact* code and the *exact* error it produces.  I can reproduce the *same* error trace you got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    tortue = turtle.Turtle()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 3816, in __init__
    visible=visible)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

By simply doing:

```
import turtle
turtle.bye()
tortue = turtle.Turtle()
```

Is there possibly some step you're leaving out of your question?  I also recommend that you name your source file something other than `Turtle.py` as that might cause confusion with the turtle library itself on a case-insensitive operating system.

Comment: import turtle
keith = turtle.Turtle()
keith.color('red')
keith.shape('square')
keith.fd(100)
keith.left(20)
keith.forward(100)
print('done')
turtle.done()

Comment: I do not think that what you said is exact because the Raise Terminator Error is appering also in this program :(

Comment: @Sopraxxx, I've taken another look and revised my answer, see if this gives you any insight.